# Tikz Plot with arrows along domain

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I am getting an error I cannot fix when compiling this minimal example. Please advise how to fix and continue. All suggestions welcome. Basically I am trying to add an arrowhead along the plot at any point desired.

The error I am getting is Dimension too large Error!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6,cap=round]
\tikzset{axes/.style={}}
 % The graphic
 \draw[style=help lines,step=1cm, dotted] (-4,-3.0) grid (7,9.0);
 \begin{scope}[style=axes]
 \draw[->] (-5,0) -- (8,0) node[below] {$x$};
 \draw[->] (0,-4)-- (0,10) node[left] {$y$};
 \foreach \x/\xtext in {-4/-4, -3/-3, -2/-2, -1/-1 , 1/\textcolor{red}{1}, 
       2/2, 3/3, 4/4, 5/5, 6/6,7/7}
 \draw[xshift=\x cm] (0pt,2.6pt) -- (0pt,-2.6pt) 
     node[below,fill=white,font=\scriptsize] {$\xtext$};
 \foreach \y/\ytext in {-3/-3, -2/-2, -1/-1, 1/1,   2/2, 3/\textcolor{cyan} 
     {3}, 4/4, 5/5, 6/6 , 7/7 , 8/8 , 9/9}
  \draw[yshift=\y cm] (2.6pt,0pt) -- (-2.6pt,0pt) 
   node[left,fill=white,font=\scriptsize]
    {$\ytext$};
   \draw[domain=3:4,smooth,variable=\x,red,->,thick,postaction={decorate, 
       decoration={markings,
       mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{<};}}}
       ] plot ({\x},{1+2*\x});
    \draw[domain=-3:3,smooth,variable=\x,red,<-,thick] plot ({\x},{4-\x}); 
   \draw[fill=white,draw=red,thick] (3,7) circle (3pt) node[] {$$};
   \draw[red,fill=red] (3,1) circle (3pt) node[] {};
    \node at (5,8) [fill=white,text=red,font=\normalsize] {$k(x)$};
   \end{scope}
  \draw[draw=cyan,fill=cyan,opacity=.3] (2.85,-3) rectangle (3.15,9);   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this happens if you do a lot of transformations. The problem goes away if you replace `scale=0.6` by `scale=1`. (Honestly, I am also surprised that it already happens for `scale=0.6`.) If you tell us precisely what you want, I am sure there will be a simple way to produce it without issues.

Comment: The output is correct but I am trying to get rid of the error. Unfortunately, I cannot change the scale=1. I have to leave it at scale=.6. I see this eliminates the error. I am trying to read the document on the marking library

Comment: Yes, but if you drop `smooth`, which is superfluous in a straight line, the error will also disappear.

Comment: Thanks Marmot I thought I had already tried that and now the error is gone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does that happen? It is a combination of `smooth` and `scale=0.6`. In this case, in which you only plot a straight line, `smooth` has no visible effect. However, one could imagine that you want to plot something where `smooth` does have a visible effect. What to do then? Just draw the thing and use a non-smooth path for adding the arrow.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,cap=round]
\tikzset{axes/.style={}}
 % The graphic
 \draw[style=help lines,step=1cm, dotted] (-4,-3.0) grid (7,9.0);
 \begin{scope}[style=axes]
 \draw[->] (-5,0) -- (8,0) node[below] {$x$};
 \draw[->] (0,-4)-- (0,10) node[left] {$y$};
 \foreach \x/\xtext in {-4/-4, -3/-3, -2/-2, -1/-1 , 1/\textcolor{red}{1}, 
       2/2, 3/3, 4/4, 5/5, 6/6,7/7}
 \draw[xshift=\x cm] (0pt,2.6pt) -- (0pt,-2.6pt) 
     node[below,fill=white,font=\scriptsize] {$\xtext$};
 \foreach \y/\ytext in {-3/-3, -2/-2, -1/-1, 1/1,   2/2, 3/\textcolor{cyan} 
     {3}, 4/4, 5/5, 6/6 , 7/7 , 8/8 , 9/9}
  \draw[yshift=\y cm] (2.6pt,0pt) -- (-2.6pt,0pt) 
   node[left,fill=white,font=\scriptsize]
    {$\ytext$};
   \draw[red,->,thick] plot[domain=3:4,smooth,variable=\x] ({\x},{1+2*\x});
   \path[postaction={decorate, 
       decoration={markings,
       mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow[red,thick]{<};}}}] 
       plot[domain=3:4,variable=\x] ({\x},{1+2*\x});   

    \draw[domain=-3:3,smooth,variable=\x,red,<-,thick] plot ({\x},{4-\x}); 
   \draw[fill=white,draw=red,thick] (3,7) circle (3pt) node[] {$$};
   \draw[red,fill=red] (3,1) circle (3pt) node[] {};
    \node at (5,8) [fill=white,text=red,font=\normalsize] {$k(x)$};
   \end{scope}
  \draw[draw=cyan,fill=cyan,opacity=.3] (2.85,-3) rectangle (3.15,9);   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Any advice for a later plot that is not a straight line ? and I cannot use scale=1.? You answered this question above as well. Thanks Marmot!